# Select (highlight) text in Dart

Tags: dart

This question is fairly fundamental but I can't find a solution anywhere. There are many examples of highlighting text in javascript with or without jQuery, but I'm having trouble figuring it out in Dart.

The [`Selection`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.Selection) and [`Range`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.Range) classes appear to support this but the documentation is kind of sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay while trying to write the question thoroughly I figured it out. It's actually quite simple.

**HTML:** `<p id='text'></p>`

**Dart:**

`var text = querySelector('#text');`

*Using Selection only:*

```
window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(text);
```

*Using Range and Selection:*

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(text);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

Both examples select all of the text inside the node. For more information on how to use `Range`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935786/how-do-i-create-a-range-object-when-i-know-just-the-character-offsets).